# zlib inflate CHUNK size has to be the same as the size used in deflation?

Tags: zlib, inflate

I followed the zlib inflate example from http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html to decompress a zipped file. Even after I defined the CHUNK size as 256KB, I see the output data of each inflate() function call is only 8KB. I knew the zipped file was deflated by using a CHUNK size of 8K, so does this mean zlib inflate's CHUNK size has to be the same as the size used in deflation?

If yes, without changing the source file, is there anyway to speed up decompression? Using a CHUNK size of 8K to decompress is slow.

Answer (score 1):

No, the chunk sizes do not have to be the same.  A valid deflate stream can be decoded by inflate using any chunk size.

> Even after I defined the CHUNK size as 256KB, I see the output data of
>   each inflate() function call is only 8KB.

From the discussion in the comments, you do not have a single deflate stream but rather a concatenation of a sequence of small deflate streams.  Do inflate that, you will need to simply restart the inflate process each time you complete a stream, which is indicated by `Z_STREAM_END` being returned by `inflate()`.  Use `inflateReset()` instead of `inflateEnd()` followed by `inflateInit()`, since that saves time and avoids unnecessary frees and allocations of memory.

There is no way to speed up the decompression beyond that.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I'm trying to debug my problem. What I saw in my code is CHUNK size is 256KB. Before inflate() call, avail_in is 54K data and avail_out is 256K; After inflate() call, avail_in is 53K data and avail_out is (256 - 8)K. Basically only 1K data is decompressed by inflate() and only 8K data is generated. So it will exit inner loop since avail_out !=0. Still trying to figure out why not all input data is decompressed.

Comment: Then the bug is not in your program but in your expectation that you were getting a single deflate stream.  `Z_STREAM_END` means that `inflate()` got to the end of the deflate stream and stopped, as it should.  The question this is what follows that?  Is it another deflate stream?  Something else?

Comment: But I thought this stream at least should decompress the whole 54K data (since avail_in is 54K) then return Z_STREAM_END. What I understand from the example in http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html is that when feeding CHUNK size data, inner loop will decompress the whole CHUNK size data to out till avail_out ==0. This is one deflate stream, right? Sorry if I misunderstood the whole concept.

Comment: I found your answer at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.compression/UuGWViGLPOY. I think I have the same problem.   (from Mark Adler "Just run inflate again like you did the first time and keep going from 
where you left off.  You have a file that is a concatenation of a 
series of gzip streams.  This is permitted by the standard, and handled 
automatically by gzip and the gz* functions in zlib. 

To restart inflate, use inflateReset() instead of inflateEnd() and 
inflateInit2(), so as to avoid unnecessary memory release and 
reallocation. "

Comment: So my source file is a concatenation of a series of zlib raw size 8K streams. It is nice that I can follow Mark's suggestion to run inflate again, but is there anyway to speed up decompression without changing source file, which is my ultimate goal? Thank you.