# Decompress appended compressed strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression, zlib, chunks

I am creating an application, where I have to store lots of string data - received in chunks.
I am trying to save it in compressed format. however, If i use zlib to compress strings and similarly append more compressed chunks to it, the decompression fails.

```
std::string allinput = "AAAA";
std::string cstr1 = compress_string( allinput );

std::string allinput2 = "BBBB";
std::string cstr2 = compress_string( allinput2 );

std::string cstr = cstr1 + cstr2;

std::string out = decompress_string( cstr );
std::cout << "DECOMP:" << out << "\n" ;
```

With the above code I get the following output :

```
AAAA
```

Is there some method to decompress appended chunks of compressed strings

PS: implementation of `compress_string` and `decompress_string` can be found from [C++ Code Snippet - Compressing STL Strings with zlib](https://panthema.net/2007/0328-ZLibString.html)

Comment: This question is too broad and can be answered even by "Yes", "No" and "Maybe". Please be more specific. What is the context? What is the compression scheme? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jodocus edited the question to add more details

Comment: I retracted my vote. Note that I did not downvote, though.

Comment: decompress_string must restart the parser after you saw a Z_STREAM_END https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053154

Comment: Decompressing, do you want to somehow be able to retrieve the chunk boundaries used during compression?

Comment: @greybeard that can be a viable solution, but what I really wan t to know is that, is there a compression scheme, which can decompress appended compressed blocks

Comment: @Rudi can you kindly help with more details on how to exactly go about restarting the parser.

Comment: @AnuragSaran I guess you wrote `decompress_string` yourself, and are using the zlib api there. When the zlib api sees a stream end code, it writes the seen bytes to the zlib stream, and returns Z_STREAM_END at this point. You can than inspect the stream state, and look if there are input bytes left. If so, you can start the inflate a second (third...) time, to fetch the following stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of adding compressed chunks will not work well, and you have to replace that interface, https://panthema.net/2007/0328-ZLibString.html to zlib.

If you look inside zlib you see that the compression-routine `deflate` will stop when it runs out of data to compress, based on `avail_in`. 
Set that to the amount of data you have, and increase when you get the new string.

(If you want to have useable results at every step it becomes more complicated.)

Compressing multiple strings separately and adding them together would be possible, but is a bad idea. It will add overhead, and give worse result since compression is based on patterns within the input data and by compressing multiple times you have to re-discover the patterns in each input.